# Pass number of for loop elements to external command

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using for loop to iterate through .txt files in a directory and grab specified rows from the files. Afterwards the output is passed to `pr` command in order to print it as a table. Everything works fine, however I'm manually specifying the number of columns that the table should contain. This is cumbersome when the number of files is not constant.

The command I'm using:

```
for f in *txt; do awk -F"\t" 'FNR ~ /^(2|6|9)$/{print $2}' $f; done | pr -ts --column 4
```

How should I modify the command to replace '4' with elements number?

**Edit**:
The fundamental question was if one can provide matching files number to function outside the loop. Seeing the solutions I guess it is not possible to work around the problem. Until this conclusion the structure of the files was not really relevant.
However taking the above into account, I'm providing the files structure below.

Sample file.txt:

```
Irrelevant1 text
Placebo 1222327
Irrelevant1 text
Irrelevant2 text
Irrelevant3 text
Treatment1  105956
Irrelevant1 text
Irrelevant2 text
Treatment2  49271
Irrelevant1 text
Irrelevant2 text
```

The `for` loop generates the following from 4 `*txt` files:

```
1222327
105956
49271
969136
169119
9672
1297357
237210
11581
1189529
232095
13891
```

Expected `pr` output using a dynamically generated `--column 4`:

```
1222327 969136  1297357 1189529
105956  169119  237210  232095
49271   9672    11581   13891
```

Comment: It's hard to follow your examples as I'm missing the right *txt files. However, you may try `column -t` instead of `pr`.. Like this: `for f in *txt; do awk -F"\t" 'FNR ~ /^(6|9|24)$/{print $2}' $f; done | column -t` ... Let me know if that works

Comment: could you update the question to show the output from the `for` loop for, say, 5 files? also provide the expected output of piping that into `pr`

Comment: As you are already using `awk`, rewrite it so that you don't print but instead collect the values in a two-dimensional array. One dimension would count the items from each file, the other one the number of files (which you can determine by checking for `FNR==1`). Then, at the `END` print your table as desired. That way, you don't even need the outside `for` loop, as you can feed awk with all the files at once: `awk '…' *.txt`.

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you come up with the right solution, otherwise we're just guessing at what you really need and so YMMV.

Comment: count the number of files beforehand and place in a variable (eg,`fcount`) *then* initiate the `for ... | pr -ts --column "${fcount}"`; the `for` and `pr` are started at the same time so the `pr` command line is parsed/processed prior to anything the `for` loop could possibly generate to use on the `pr` command line; another idea would include breaking the `for ...| pr ...` into two standalone commands with the `for` loop redirecting stdout to a file and the `pr` command reading from said file; another idea if the piped commands is a requirement is to rethink the logic and sub-commands used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all input files generate the same number of output lines (otherwise we can add some code to keep track of the max number of lines and generate blank columns as needed)

Setup (columns are tab-delimited):

```
$ grep -n xxx f[1-4].txt
f1.txt:6:xxx    1222327
f1.txt:9:xxx    105956
f1.txt:24:xxx   49271
f2.txt:6:xxx    969136
f2.txt:9:xxx    169119
f2.txt:24:xxx   9672
f3.txt:6:xxx    1297357
f3.txt:9:xxx    237210
f3.txt:24:xxx   11581
f4.txt:6:xxx    1189529
f4.txt:9:xxx    232095
f4.txt:24:xxx   13891
```

One idea using `awk` to dynamically build the 'table' (replaces OP's current `for` loop):

```
awk -F'\t' '
FNR==1             { c=0 }
FNR ~ /^(6|9|24)$/ { ++c ; arr[c]=arr[c] (FNR==NR ? "" : " ") $2 }
END                { for (i=1;i<=c;i++) print arr[i] }
' f[1-4].txt | column -t -o ' '
```

**NOTE:** we'll go ahead and let `column` take care of pretty-printing the table with a single space separating the columns, otherwise we could add some more code to `awk` to right-pad columns with spaces

This generates:

```
1222327 969136 1297357 1189529
105956  169119 237210  232095
49271   9672   11581   13891
```

Comment: very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just run ls and pipe the output to wc -l. Then once you've got that number you can assign it to a variable and place that variable in your command.

```
num=$(ls *.txt | wc -l)
```

I forget how to place bash variables in AWK, but I think you can do that. If not, respond back and I'll try to find a different answer.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs